# как запретить доступ сервису к авторизации через github?

Tags: git, github

Зашла по авторизации на сайт codesandbox.io, выбрала авторизацию через github, хочу в настройках github отключить данную авторизацию как бы сделать запрет доступа, например через гугл авторизовываетесь и потом можно в личном кабинете прекратить доступ, но не могу найти такого.

Comment: https://github.com/settings/applications

Comment: На главной странице жмете на аватарку пользователя в правом верхнем углу, Settings -> Applications -> вкладка Authorized OAuth Apps.